# how to build a string variable to capture muti cols info

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

It can be build using codes:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Pass = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Math = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ELA = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0), PE = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Where `pass` stand for a student pass any test or not. Now I want to build a new var `Result` to capture a student's test results like following, what should I do?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the base R code below

```
q <- with(data.frame(which(df[-(1:2)] == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)),
          tapply(names(df[-(1:2)])[col], factor(row, levels = 1:nrow(df)), toString))
df$Result <- ifelse(is.na(q), "Not Pass", paste0("Pass: ", q))
```

which gives

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 6
     ID  Pass  Math   ELA    PE Result            
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             
1     1     0     0     0     0 Not Pass          
2     2     1     0     1     0 Pass: ELA          
3     3     1     1     0     1 Pass: Math, PE     
4     4     1     1     1     1 Pass: Math, ELA, PE
5     5     1     1     0     1 Pass: Math, PE
```

Comment: This is so neat!! Where are `row` and `col` coming from though?

Comment: @Dunois Coming from `which` with option `arr.ind = TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Pass = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
               Math = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ELA = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0), PE = c(0, 
                                                                       0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))



df %<>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Pass), names_to = "sub", values_to = "done")

df %<>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Result = paste0(ifelse(done == 1, sub, NA), collapse = ", ")) %>% ungroup()

df %<>% pivot_wider(names_from = sub, values_from = done)

df %<>% mutate(Result = paste0("Pass: ", str_replace_all(Result, "NA[, ]*", "")))

df %<>% mutate(Result = ifelse(str_detect(Result, "Pass: $"), "Not pass", str_replace_all(Result, ",[\\s]*$", "")))

df

# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#      ID  Pass Result               Math   ELA    PE
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0 Not pass                0     0     0
# 2     2     1 Pass: ELA               0     1     0
# 3     3     1 Pass: Math, PE          1     0     1
# 4     4     1 Pass: Math, ELA, PE     1     1     1
# 5     5     1 Pass: Math, PE          1     0     1
```

I can provide an explanation of what the code is doing if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` with `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(Result = if(as.logical(Pass)) 
      str_c('Pass: ', toString(names(select(., Math:PE))[as.logical(c_across(Math:PE))])) else 'Not pass' ) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#     ID  Pass  Math   ELA    PE Result             
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              
#1     1     0     0     0     0 Not pass           
#2     2     1     0     1     0 Pass: ELA          
#3     3     1     1     0     1 Pass: Math, PE     
#4     4     1     1     1     1 Pass: Math, ELA, PE
#5     5     1     1     0     1 Pass: Math, PE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Pass = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Math = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ELA = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0), PE = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```